# What happens when you have two races?

Tags: dnd-4e, races, player-characters

I've been searching for a bit now and have found nothing.

My character is a Human paladin but is also eladrin, So what the specifics towards these rules, like could I take all the racial powers from both races or do I have to choose half and half, is there a specific thing in one of the handbooks? I haven't been finding a lot.

Also, I use homebrews so if there isn't something in the handbook then Homebrews would work too.

But any things really fine, thx!

Comment: How can your character be a human while being an eladrin? To determine what happens we need to know what caused it (and if the only way is homebrewing, we can't help you)

Answer (score 6):

There aren't rules for mixing races. There *are* some hints how multi-racial PCs would work.

Half Elf may work for your intent, they are a mixed race between humans and elves and would be the best RAW solution to your conundrum.

However a homebrew solution may be in order.

The best example of this would be the Revanant, who has a feat that allows you to crib a racial power from another class (though you can't use both your racial feature *and* the other in the same encounter).

A convenient house rule would be to have the character take Human as their primary race with the Heroic Effort power, and give them a feat to take the Eladrin's racial encounter teleport power. Then allow them to use either as their encounter power for any given encounter.

Answer (score 4):

**Sounds Like a Half-Elf to Me**

If you're descended from a human and an Eladrin, you're a half elf, as Eladrin are just more magical elves. Sadly, you can't be two "races" at once. You can, however, have different lineages which factor into your race or class. In various editions, dragons have produced offspring, giving us Dragonborn and/or Sorcerers.

You may want to home-brew a Half-Eladrin, using the Eladrin racial traits and the Half-Elf racial traits as a guide. Of course, all home-brewed things should be approved by a DM before use in play!

Comment: Related Note: Although there are plenty of instances of D&D mixing "races" to form new "races," Wizards of the Coast often ignore real-world biology. The fact that most species of real-world creatures can't cross-breed, and those that do often produce inviable offspring, is missing. If their races *are* actually races, then why are there only half-elves, and not other half things?

Comment: Because TSR wanted to scoop Tolkien's half-elves (who are elf or half-elf based on spiritual allegiance, which is a choice), but to avoid getting sued they used a BS biological explanation. And so 40 years of confusion over half-breeds began.

Comment: @PipperChip do note that races can interbreed. Species are the ones that are defined in part by "can't interbreed".

Answer (score 3):

By the rules, you can't BE two races at once.  So anything you get will be made up.  If you're the DM of your game, you decide.  If you're not, ask your DM, as he or she's the only one who can really say for their game.  Most likely, the best way to handle it is to creature a new race, Half-Eladrin, that gets some part of each race's powers, but the DM has to be involved in that process.

Comment: It is fine by him, and what I'm asking is like multi-classing, there must be some things I can and can't do with the racials

Comment: @gyhome basically you either need to home brew it as a flavor of half elf, or just take the half elf racial background. Both Eladrin and Humans have very strong and very different racial features, whatever you do you should not get the benefits of both races together.

Comment: Multi-classing is like learning both how to play DnD and how to play video games.  Being two different races is like having two blue eyes and two brown eyes.  That's why I suggest letting the DM decide what to do, since there is literally no rules for it.  Creating a new race (Half-Eladrin) is probably your best shot, but race creation MUST involve the DM in every step of the process.